# How can a written language develop with unspoken letters?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling

English is a language in which you write quite a few letters that you do not pronounce, or you write letters in one order and pronounce it in another.

For example, *centre*. It is pronounced /ˈsɛn.tə(r)/, so you say *e* before *r*, but you write it the other way around. Or *Google*: /ˈɡuːɡəl/; you say *e* before *l*, and then you write it the other way around.

One example of a letter written but not spoken would be *practically*. You say *practic-ly*.

There are quite a few examples of that. But I don't see why those things seem to develop.

I am a German, and (most of the time, with a few exceptions) we speak all the letters written (or at least significantly change the pronunciation of the other letters at some points).